# Split a string into two substring in C#

Tags: c#

How can i get the string "tulip" from the string "tulip.jpg" using Split function in c#?

```
string str = "tulip.jpg";
```

I store the result "tulip" in str1(string type valiable).

Comment: You are trying to re-invent what already exists in .NET!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx couldn't be more obvious. Have you googled at all?

Comment: [how to split a string by a character in c#](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+split+a+string+by+a+character+in+c%23&oq=how+to+split+a+string+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l2j0l3.6952j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: google + 5 seconds = http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: @BartTeunissen And it couldn't be more obvious that the string contains a filename, in which case `string.split` is entirely the wrong answer. Have you read the question at all?

Comment: Love how you all leap to pull the OP down, but then provide a flawed solution...

Comment: He could split his string on the dot using string split function. (and yeah, this doesn't work if there are more that one dot in the path).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a filename, so i wouldn't use `String.Split` but the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)-methods:

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("tulip.jpg");
```

For what it's worth: `fileNameOnly = "tulip.jpg".Split('.')[0];`

This will be a problem if the name also contains dots.

So if you insist on string methods `String.Substring` or `String.Remove` would be better:

```
fileNameOnly = fileName.Remove(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - if your problem is within the domain of filenames / paths, and the functionality exists within the Framework to allow you to do the job in that context, then use it.